# iOS Cordova assets not loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I wrote some new views for my application, and they all show up properly on chrome and safari. However, when I run the app on simulator and open up the safari debugger, those views don't show up under `index.html/scripts/`. I have confirmed that those files exist in the `www/` and `Staging/www/` folders in the Xcode project. I have run `rake prepare_ios`, but it does not fix the issue, do I need to add these new files to a directory somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to access my application through mobile Safari, I encountered an error on the Safari inspector that I had hooked to my simulator. It told me that I could not use `const` since I was using `strict` mode. This error had not popped up previously, and only out of random luck (when i was closing the safari tab) did it even show up on the inspector. This led me to go and make changes to my files that were using `const` and the page loads now.